# Why can't I get the records in database after I save it in mongoDB with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, save

I connect to database:

```
mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://mongo:27017/docker-node-mongo', { useNewUrlParser: true})
```

With this Schema:

```
const ItemSchema = new Schema({name: { type: String,required: true},date: {type: Date,default: Date.now}});
module.exports = Item = mongoose.model('item', ItemSchema);
```

I create 2 Schema objects to be saved

```
const newItem1 = new Item({
    name: "Item1"
});

const newItem2 = new Item({
    name: "Item34"
});
```

I save them

```
Item1.save()
Item2.save()
```

But when I search for the records; I cant find anything.It prints an empty array I suppose:

```
Item.find({}).then(result => console.log(result));
//[]
```

If I run the program again, now the records show up. I need to be able to find and get the saved database objects after the save(not in callback functions or anything.) How can I do it directly after the save line ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't find items because all functions run asynchronous.
You should read about asynchronous and synchronous.

in this case will use "async function" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

```
// use async function
const main = async () => {
  const item1 = new Item({
    name: 'Item 1',
  });

  const item2 = new Item({
    name: 'Item 2',
  });

  // save item 1
  await item1.save();

  // save item 2 after save item 1
  await item2.save();

  // get all items after save item 1 and item 2
  const result = await Item.find({});

  console.log(result);
};

main();
```

We can improve this code by using asynchronous in item 1 and item 2

```
// use async function
const main = async () => {
  const item1 = new Item({
    name: 'Item 1',
  });

  const item2 = new Item({
    name: 'Item 2',
  });

  // save item1 and item2 in parallel
  await Promise.resolve(item1.save, item2.save);

  // get all items after save item 1 and item 2
  const result = await Item.find({});

  console.log(result);
};

main();
```